# Webpack add watch mode without compiling

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have the following npm scripts:

```
"build:server:dev": "webpack --config ./webpack.server.dev.config.js --watch",
"build:client:dev": "webpack --config ./webpack.client.dev.config.js --watch",
"build:server:prod": "webpack --config ./webpack.server.prod.config.js",
"build:client:prod": "webpack --config ./webpack.client.prod.config.js",
"start:server:prod": "export NODE_ENV=production && node ./dist/server.*.js",
"start:iso:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run build:client:dev & npm run build:server:dev",
"start:iso:dev:win": "set NODE_ENV=development && concurrently --kill-others \"npm run build:client:dev\" \"npm run build:server:dev\"",
"start:iso:prod": "npm run build:client:prod && npm run build:server:prod && npm run start:server:prod"
```

The problem I'm facing is that the server compilation depends on the client compilation (I generate an html template where I inject the scripts with webpack on the client, and I use this template for server rendering in the server script).
In nearly all of the cases, the client finishes compiling before the server, but while running these scripts concurrently, there is no way to ensure that this will always be true.
When running webpack watch mode, it is not possible to run these scripts in sequence, as watch mode will block the second script from running.

The most obvious solution in my mind is to compile them without watch mode once, and then attach watch mode on the fly after the initial compilation.
I'm not sure how to achieve this though, and I would not like to compile them twice, just for the sake of attaching watch mode.

The second alternative I have in mind is to fiddle with webpack progress plugin, and somehow compile the server script after the client script has finished.
I dislike this solution, because I don't want to hard couple one script to another.

So is there a way to run client and server compilation sequentially from an npm script while using webpack --watch mode?

Comment: I had the same problem in my app, how do you "consume" the `html` file that gets generated at the client build?

Comment: @felixmosh I simply read the html file with nodejs `fs.readFile`.

Comment: Ok, so your server "starts" before the client finished it build, how do you start your server?

Comment: @felixmosh Answered. Do put your thoughts in the comments, in case you would have remarks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice solution using the npm package wait-on:

https://github.com/jeffbski/wait-on

The npm script I used (Unix & Windows):

```
"start:iso:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run clean:build && npm run build:client:dev & wait-on public/build/index-dev.html && npm run build:server:dev --inspect",
"start:iso:dev:win": "npm run clean:build:win && set NODE_ENV=development&& concurrently \"npm run build:client:dev\" \"wait-on public\\build\\index-dev.html && npm run build:server:dev\"",
```

This works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you [parallel-webpack](https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack) although I didn't try it it has watch mode and would probably just require connecting your configs for both server and client side someway along this way:

```
// some script for running parallel builds
module.exports = [
  require('./webpack.server.dev.config.js'),
  require('./webpack.client.dev.config.js'),
];
```

then check [running in watch mode](https://github.com/trivago/parallel-webpack#running-the-watcher)

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to build them in parallel but rather sequential with watch mode.

Comment: @Trace for me it looks like after everything builds sequentially for the first time you are running it in parallel but without help of parallel-webpack some build are finishing faster then others and you have some synchronization gap that should be fixed by using parallel-webpack although i didnt use it on bigger scale and am not sure if it would actually help you i would suggest to try it if there is no better idea

Comment: Running in parallel is the opposite of running sequential, you don't know which one finishes first because of the race condition. Actually, I think I've found a way to fix it. Thanks

Comment: @Trace, can you share your solution?